# Storing Insert Data on client, when mysql server is unreachable

Tags: mysql, linux, jdbc

I have a lot of clients, which want to send same data types to a mysql server in one table. But what happens to the data, if the network connection is aborted for few hours?
The whole system is on linux. Everything is connected in a own network, but it's anyway possible, that the connection aborts.
The insert commands are written in java with jdbc

Are there any techniques to store the data temporarily local on the clients and synchronize it automatically afterwards until the network connection is established.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What platform did you use for your front-end? If it is a web application, you could use store the data in local storage until you get a confirmation that the server has saved it successfully. For a desktop application, you can use any kind of local data-store from a database to a text file.

Comment: Its a desktop application. My first thoughts were to create a temporarily database table and delete it as soon as the connection is established and sent the new data. But I hoped for a tool or something else, that does it automatically. Of course I can write a script on my own, but there must be anything used by companies for such issues.

Comment: So you have a Java desktop application that uses JDBC to connect to a remote database?

Comment: Exactly! Another option is to store the data on a local database and "update" this local database in short periods (ca. 15 min) to the server. But the clients have less memory and the the data must be erased after certain time. So replication or something is impossible.

Comment: You're creating 'sendmail' for SQL queries (and potentially other network connections). It's a good idea, though I'm not sure how much interest you'll generate in today's "always connected" world paradigm. One thought: always write the queries to a file (never run them), and then have a cron job try to run them until they succeed. I use this technique to avoid having processes stall when trying to insert data.

Comment: I don't know of any 3rd party solution that does this at the database connection level. You might want to look into Message Queues. You're using Java so look into JMS. You said that the clients have less memory. Is this an embedded system of sorts? If you provide more details of your setup maybe I could suggest something more specific.